# How does index work in JanusGraph database, when we have two columns with two different indexes

Tags: indexing, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using JanusGraph 0.2.0 version. I have following two indexes in my graph.

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
keyName = mgmt.getPropertyKey('propertyKeyA')
labelName = mgmt.getVertexLabel('labelA')
mgmt.buildIndex('labelA_keyAIndex', Vertex.class).addKey(keyName).indexOnly(labelName).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'labelA_keyAIndex').call()
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("labelA_keyAIndex"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
mgmt.commit()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'labelA_keyAIndex').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()


mgmt = graph.openManagement()
keyName = mgmt.getPropertyKey("propertyKeyB")
mgmt.buildIndex("keyBIndex",Vertex.class).addKey(keyName).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "keyBIndex").call();
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("keyBIndex"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
mgmt.commit()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'keyBIndex').status(SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()


g.V().hasLabel("labelA").has("propertyKeyB","value").has("propertyKeyA","value").valueMap()
```

1) will the above query use **both index**  or only **labelA_KeyAIndex**?

I am using **propertyKeyB** with many other label in the graph, so I have created a seperate index for propertyKeyB **keyBIndex** without specifying `indexOnly(label)`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish you wouldn't use the world column(s) in graph(s) it can become very confusing very quickly. That said, append .profile() to the end of a traversal to see what indexes are used. In JanusGraph, graph indexes are only used for the initial lookup thereafter, Vertex-Centric indexes take over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify the behavior by using the [`profile()`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#profile-step) step on your traversal

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("labelA").has("propertyKeyB","value").has("propertyKeyA","value").valueMap().profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[~label.eq(labelA), propertyK...                                             0.422    94.51
    \_condition=(~label = labelA AND propertyKeyB = value AND propertyKeyA = value)
    \_isFitted=true
    \_query=multiKSQ[1]@2147483647
    \_index=keyBIndex
    \_orders=[]
    \_isOrdered=true
  optimization                                                                                 0.255
PropertyMapStep(value)                                                                         0.024     5.49
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           0.447        -
```

You can see in the profile output that `keyBIndex` is the one that is chosen.